# Using custom method inside Linq Select with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

I am trying to use a custom Function inside a Linq Select that is used with EF.
I want to project each item of tblMitarbeiter onto one tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories that is valid ad the given date.
This should be done with an extension method so that I do not repeat myself ;)
I can only get it to work when used directly on the DbSet, but not inside a Select.

How can I teach EF to recognize my Method (3.) as if I would be writing it out (1.)?

```
void Main()
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;

    // 1. works, returns IEnumerable<tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories>
    tblMitarbeiters
    .Select(m => m.tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories.Where(p => p.ZuordnungGültigAb <= date).OrderByDescending(p => p.ZuordnungGültigAb).FirstOrDefault())
    .Dump();

    // 2. works, returns one tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories
    tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories
    .GetValidItemForDate(p => p.ZuordnungGültigAb, date)
    .Dump();

    // 3. throws NotSupportedException
    tblMitarbeiters
    .Select(m => m.tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories.GetValidItemForDate(p => p.ZuordnungGültigAb, date))
    .Dump();

    // 4. throws NotSupportedException
    tblMitarbeiters
    .Select(m => m.tblMitarbeiterPersonalkostenstelleHistories.AsQueryable().GetValidItemForDate(p => p.ZuordnungGültigAb, date))
    .Dump();
}


public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static T GetValidItemForDate<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> selector, DateTime date)
    {
        var dateAccessor = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(Expression.Constant(date), selector.Parameters);
        var lessThanOrEqual = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(selector.Body, dateAccessor.Body);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(lessThanOrEqual, selector.Parameters);
        return source.Where(lambda).OrderByDescending(selector).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static T GetValidItemForDate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, DateTime> selector, DateTime date) =>
        source.Where(i => selector(i) <= date).OrderByDescending(selector).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Robust way - call `ToList()` before your `Select` with custom method. It works, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: I want to it on the server, not in memory. `ToList()` would either need an Include (bad performance) or a lot of lazy loading (even worse performance)

Comment: Well, there are [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) which could be called inside IQueryable (on database side), but if you want more than that you should use stored procedure or load it in memory.

Comment: My method cann already be decomposed into simple linq functions that are recognized by EF (1.), so there is no need for SqlFunctions.

Answer (score 2):

You can, to some extent, split up complex LINQ expressions using [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). If you'll excuse me, I'll use an example model that's less germanic:

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeHistoryRecord> HistoryRecords { get; set; } 
}

public class EmployeeHistoryRecord
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

If I understood your question correctly, it should be identical to yours where it matters.

When using LINQKit, and LINQ in general, you must understand that the only tool you have at your disposal when reusing query code, without using stored procedures, is breaking apart and stitching together expressions.

Your utility method would translate to something like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TItem>, TItem>> GetValidItemForDate<TItem>(
            Expression<Func<TItem, DateTime>> dateSelector, 
            DateTime date)
{
    return Linq.Expr((IEnumerable<TItem> items) =>
        items.Where(it => dateSelector.Invoke(it) <= date)
            .OrderByDescending(it => dateSelector.Invoke(it))
            .FirstOrDefault())
        .Expand();
}
```

What this method does is dynamically create an expression whose input is an `IEnumerable<TItem>` that returns a `TITem`. You can see it's pretty similar to the code you're extracting. A few things to note:

- The source collection is not a parameter of the utility method, but of the expression returned.
- You have to call the `Invoke()` extension method from LinqKit on any expressions you're "plugging into" this one.
- You should call `Expand()` on the result if you used any `Invoke()`s inside it. This will make LINQKit replace the calls to `Invoke()` in the expression tree with the expression being invoked. (This isn't 100% necessary, but it makes it easier to fix errors when expansion fails for some reason. If you don't `Expand()` in every helper method, any error that happens during expansion will manifest in the method that does the expansion, and not in the method that actually contains the offending code.)

You then use this similarly, again using `Invoke()`:

```
var db = new EmployeeHistoryContext();

var getValidItemForDate = GetValidItemForDate((EmployeeHistoryRecord cab) => cab.ValidFrom, DateTime.Now);

var historyRecords = db.Employees.AsExpandable().Select(emp => getValidItemForDate.Invoke(emp.HistoryRecords));
```

(I've only tested this code against an empty database, insofar that it doesn't make EntityFramework throw a `NotSupportedException`.)

Here, you should note:

- The subexpression you're plugging into the one you're passing into `Select()` needs to be saved in a local variable, LINQKit doesn't support method calls during expansion.
- You need to call `AsExpandable()` on the first `IQueryable` in the chain, so LINQKit gets to work its magic.
- You're probably not going to be able to use extension method call syntax inside the expression like in your question.
- All the subexpressions have to be determined before expansion occurs.

These limitations stem from the fact that what you're doing isn't really calling methods. You're building one ginormous expression from a bunch of smaller ones, but the resulting expression itself still has to be something that LINQ-to-Entities will understand. On the other hand, the input has to be something LINQKit will understand, and it only handles expressions of the form `localVariable.Invoke()`. Any dynamism has to be in the code outside this expression tree. Basically, it's doing the same as your solution 2, just using syntax more intuitive than building the expression tree programmatically.

Last, but not least: when doing this, do not go overboard. Complex EF queries are already really hard to debug when anything goes wrong, because you're not told where in your code the problem is. If the query was assembled dynamically from bits and pieces all over your codebase, debugging some errors (like the delightful "Unable to cast the type `X` to type `Y`") will easily become a nightmare.

---

(For future questions: I think it's usually a good idea when if you make a code sample from scratch, instead of using bits from your actual codebase. They might be overly domain-specific, and understanding the names might require some context you take for granted. Identifiers should ideally be simple English names everyone can understand. I can maybe speak enough German to interview for a job in it, but "Mitarbeiterpersonalkostenstellehistorie" is just hard to keep in my head and reason about when I haven't actually worked on your project long enough to be familiar with what it's supposed to mean.)